# How to disable swagger-codegen java.io.InputStream conversion

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I got rests that return:

```
java.io.InputStream,
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,
org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamRecource
```

But in result `swagger-codegen` generated API, I got rests, that return:

```
productName.client.model.InputStream,
ErrorModelNamenamespacecomFasterxmlJacksonDatabindNameJsonNode,
productName.client.model.InputStreamResource
```

I can't ignore them by `.swagger-codegen-ignore`

And i think that replacing `java.io.InputStream` by `byte[]` is not good (how it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211304/how-to-handle-org-springframework-core-io-resource-for-swagger-codegen)). Cause stream has some pluses, such as exclusion of memory leaks.

What interesting, Swagger understand, that classes from `springframework.http` must not be converted. I got them all as original in generated API.

Is it possible to save `java.io.InputStream` and `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamRecource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done by

`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar generate --import-mappings InputStreamResource=org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource,JsonNode=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,InputStream=java.io.InputStream -DhideGenerationTimestamp=true -i "http://$CONTAINER_IP:8080/app_name/rest/v3/api-docs" -l java --library resttemplate -o app_name-api-client`

or through

`.swagger-codegen-ignore` file by add `/src/main/java/app_name/client/InputStreamResource`